# Атрибут NOINHERIT для роли в PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, администрирование

Пытаюсь изучать администрирование PostgresQL, столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при попытке создать домен от имени пользователя user, который является владельцем текущей базы данных, PostgresQL выдает ошибку. От этой ошибки можно избавиться, если дополнительно изменить владельца схемы на user. Но вот что интересно: если роль user была создана с атрибутом INHERIT, то ошибка не проявляется, а если с атрибутом NOINHERIT, то проявляется. При вызове команды \du выводится информация, что роль user не является членом ни какой иной роли. Вопрос следующий: откуда роль user берет себе права на создание домена?